# Has the yada-yada operator been deprecated?

Tags: perl, operators

I can't find the [yada-yada](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/perlop.html#Yada-Yada-Operator) documented in perldoc's 5.16.0 edition of [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Nor do I see any deprecation notice in [`perldoc perl5160delta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5160delta.html). Is it still there?

Comment: I don't have access to v5.16.0, else I would have tried it myself and found out!

Comment: I assume that v5.16 is too fresh and its documentation still has some glitches, maybe that's why it's missing from `perldoc`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it is still there.  Search for "yada" in [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) (5.16.0):

> Note: Some folks colloquially refer to this bit of punctuation as a
>   "yada-yada" or "triple-dot", but its true name is actually an
>   ellipsis.

Comment: BTW, I found this by going to the CPAN page and doing a `grep` on `yada`: http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.0

Comment: @Zaid, One has never been able to use inside an expression. It was never an operator.

Comment: @ikegami : It may never have been an operator, but it certainly was [referred to as an operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/perlop.html#Yada-Yada-Operator)

Comment: @Zaid, I know. I didn't comment on that part of your comment.